# htaccess rewrite .html not required / is optional

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a working website, with atleast 500 pages ranked in Google.
All pages have .html at end of page.
Now I want to remove .html of all pages, but let the pages in Google (with `.html`) keep there index.

After searching I cant find the correct answer. 
I know the ? is for optional. I tried 2 Rules behind eachother but didnt work too.

Here is what my htaccess now is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ find_page.php?redirect=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

I tried with adding:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ find_page.php?redirect=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

So if URL contains no extension use this rule, else use the normal rule (with `htaccess`)

I should expect my rule should be something like this: `^(.*)(?\.html)$`
So my goal is: With or without html should work, but `.php` shouldnt be work :-)

Comment: What speaks against reading a small introduction about "regular expressions" if you want to use them? This is all explained in detail. You just have to read it. Why ask here instead? I mean remember school days? When you learned something because you read something about it? That actually worked! Great, wasn't it?

Comment: @arkascha What kind of comment is this? Offcourse I read regular expressions. I know some things about it but that doesnt make me a master. Why you are going to school? Because a teacher will show you something and give you advise, this is all what I do! I tried, I failed, I ask for help.

Comment: Sorry, you are certainly right complaining that my comment has been to harsh. And that it wasn't a constructive comment. I do apologize, such thing does not belong here. But please also understand how frustrating it is to see all these questions  where people obviously read 5 lines about something, decide "hm, no idea" and then just dump their question here. Instead this place should be for real issues, where people need help. Your question is answered in about 5 million examples on google. For example they all show where the `?` belongs.

Comment: @arkascha apologize approved :-) I know, a lot of people do like you explain. My way of answer this questions is but search on Google for them, add the links and let these people read. By reminding them if they tried Google is I think the best way. Anyway, thanks for your reply, if you know how to solve should make a good contibute :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why look for a complex solution?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ find_page.php?redirect=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ find_page.php?redirect=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This rewrites all request to that php script, adding the original "file name" as parameter "redirect" and preserves all query parameters. That is what you asked for in your question.

But a warning: you can do this and it will allow to rewrite requests to for example page "redirection" as `.../redirection?somearg` or `.../redirection.html?somearg`. But for google both request are completely different pages. This will *not* help you to preserve any ratings when shifting to the new request scheme.

And a general side note: *if* you have control over the http server configuration, then you should *always* prefer to place such rules in the hosts configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Such files are notoriously error prone, make things complex, are hard to debug and really slow the server down. They should only be used in two cases: if you do *not* have control over the http server configuration or if you require your scripts to do dynamic changes to your ruleset (which is always a very insecure thing).

Comment: a VERY constructive answer! You make some good points! Thanks for that! I tried and seems to work without any problems. I know about the arguments but use only one style. I want Google to cache the links without, but if someone has a link with the extension, it should get the same page and not a 404 or something.  The general note is good to be aware of. I knew it, but I think a lot of people dont. Anyway, thanks for your answer. Learned something new ;-)

Comment: in the rule the .html is given to the redirect what shouldnt happen...i try to fix it, if you have a solution, let me know!

Comment: Indeed, I see your point. There probably is a more compact solution but currently the most straight forward is what I posted in the updated answer above. It is _two_ rules no, first the one matching the trainling `.html`, then the more general one. Since rules are processed sequencially that should work around that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$      $1.html
```

You don't need `find_page.php` for redirection. As it mentioned in other answer `http://server/folder/file` and `http://server/folder/file.html` becomes the same for the user but different for the Google.

This does not affect to PHP, folders and other content. It just tries to add «.html» to requested URL if it does not point a file or folder.

I've checked, it works fine even user queries uri with anchor like `1.html#bookmark1`

Comment: I dont think you read my question correctly. I have a rewrite already, want to remove the .html from the filename but hold the possibility to access the correct file when .html is added (because caching of Google)

Comment: @eL-Prova I didn't understand what files actually present in folders? Is it correct that .html fies still present and you want just access them with and withot extentions?

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I changed the answer.

Comment: I think we have miscommunication...the html file is just a name. Pages are stored in the database. First to act like real pages, i create <domain>/<filename>.html. Now i want to have <domain>/<filename> only, but when someone access by the old style, it should show the same page

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved my problem.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.html([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.html find_page.php?redirect=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ find_page.php?redirect=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

With this option there will be checked if the page has .html optional at end. If it has, will the first rule be matched, else will go further and use the second rule which has no html at the end